# Update component when props update

Tags: reactjs

I would like my `Booklist` to update whenever `newBooks` is updated (Sorry I'm a total newbie). Here's my code:

```
function App() {
  const [newBooks, setNewBooks] = useState([]);

  const handleNewBook = (newBook) => {
    const fullList = newBooks
    fullList.push(newBook)
    setNewBooks(fullList)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Booklist books={books} newBooks={newBooks} />
      <AddBook handle={handleNewBook}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Number one rule of React - [never mutate state](https://medium.com/@kkranthi438/dont-mutate-state-in-react-6b25d5e06f42)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push` mutates the array. You need to create a new array to make react infrastructure aware of the change

```
const handleNewBook = (newBook) => {
  setNewBooks(books => books.concat(newBook))
}
```

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#app'))

function App() {
  const [newBooks, setNewBooks] = React.useState(['aaaaa', 'bbb', 'Harry Potter']);

  const handleNewBook = (newBook) => {
    setNewBooks((books) => books.concat(newBook));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Booklist books={newBooks} />
      <AddBook handle={handleNewBook} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Booklist({ books }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {books.map((book) => (
        <li key={book}>{book}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function AddBook({ handle }) {
  const [book, setBook] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="book"
        value={book}
        placeholder="Enter book"
        onChange={(e) => setBook(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handle(book);
          setBook("");
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Comment: Simply to use ecma script syntax as the following.  **setNewBooks([...books, newBook]**

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is good so problem lies at the `handleNewBook` function call in the `AddBook` component try to pass a param of a Book in the `handleNewBook()`.

```
<AddBook handle={() => handleNewBook(YOUR_ELEMENT_TO_ADD_TO_ARRAY)}/>
```

To test this try printing a book in your `handleNewBook` function you will surely get `undefined` so you need to pass an argument to the function.

Comment: What is `Book` in your code example? And why would you need to create yet another wrapper around `handleNewBook` function?

Comment: Actually Book is just a placeholder i put in the code since add don't know how he is adding a Book so is a placeholder for any object

Comment: Placeholder? How do you suggest it would be "filled" then?

Comment: Check my answer again just made some edits

Comment: It still makes no sense. :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko try to test the code provided in the question and print the book param you will surely find undefined so my code simply add an argument to the function call.

Comment: Code is not complete to run it. But clearly the problem is that OP mutates the array.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko here is my explanation the function handleNewBook expects a parameter as per its definition in the code expecting a parameter book it got undefined as a value since no argument was passed, So solved try we put an argument let's say 1 so the call becomes handleNewBook(1) but also this throws a too may renders error by react so in the end we do () => handleNewBook(1)  now the  YOUR_ELEMENT_TO_ADD_TO_ARRAY can be any value a number or a string am just not sure the books datatype to be used. THanks

Comment: "a parameter book it got undefined as a value since no argument was passed, " how do you know? OP hasn't provided any code calling the function. Also by wrapping it with anonymous function w/o arguments you are eliminating any possibility to pass the parameter on the calling site. Unless you do some weird stuff to mutate global `YOUR_ELEMENT_TO_ADD_TO_ARRAY` or whatever you call it. It just makes no sense.

Comment: <AddBook handle={handleNewBook}/> this is the function call

Comment: Well, just for the sake of learning try to create a fully working example. I did it for my answer :)

Comment: Technically it is, but not the one you think of. It calls `createElement` or `jsx` runtime. To be clear `handle={handleNewBook}` is not a function call. It just passes function as a property.

Comment: take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-violet-6fmp1

Comment: It doesn't work https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-kapitsa-y8phu :)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bush-nmu9w?file=/src/App.js  check the console

Comment: I doesn't matter what you log in console. Child component still have empty list. Just check the UI in my link. It always shows empty array. Same as it is in OPs case. It seems you'll never learn, so let's consider this discussion closed :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will throw an error. 'books' is not defined. Do this instead.

```
function App() {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);// pass the variable here if you have initial data.

  const handleNewBook = (newBook) => {
 setBooks(prev=>[...prev,newBook]); //using spread oprator to push data in array
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Booklist books={books}/><!-- make sure you have looped the data. like props.books.map(value=> your html with value) inside Booklist component-->
      <AddBook handle={handleNewBook}/> <!-- make sure you have used props.handle('book-name') on any events. like onClick={()=>props.handle('book-name')} in AddBook component-->
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mutate directly the state without using a "setState" function. So you just pass a new array with the previous values (spread operator) and the new value (if it's an object)

```
const handleNewBook = (newBook) => {
  setNewBooks((books) => [...books, newBook]);
}; // You need to use the previous state
```

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-bhaskara-g9e9t?file=/src/App.js)